# Form bindAndSave method doesn't save files

Tags: forms, symfony1, symfony-1.4, save

Parsing an XML feed and save it this way:

```
$action = new CouponActionForm();
$values = array(
      'name' => $offer->name,
      'link' => $offer->url,
      'description' => $offer->description,
      'discount' => $offer->discount,
      'price' => $offer->price
);
$files = $this->getImages($offer->picture);
if(!$action->bindAndSave($values, $files)){
      echo $action->renderGlobalErrors();
      die('BAD THING');
}
```

Here is the `getImages` method:

```
private function getImages($url){
  $ret = array('error' => 0);
  $tmp_dir = sys_get_temp_dir();
  $tmp_file = tempnam($tmp_dir, 'kupon');
  if(copy($url, $tmp_file)){
      $ret['tmp_name'] = $tmp_file;
      $ret['name'] = basename($url);
      $ret['size'] = filesize($tmp_file);
      $ret['type'] = 'image/jpeg';
      return array('filename' => $ret);
  }else{
      die('HELP');
  }
}
```

Why do I use form saving instead of object saving with `->fromArray` method ? Well, I already made the form and all validation, so I don't want to implement the same thing twice (DRY), but as important, I actually don't know how to use validators in doctrine model.
So the problem is that the form doesn't save files in specific directory specified by the `path` property of `sfValidatorFile` validator, but it exists in tmp directory.

Comment: As far as I remember it is the File Validator which is responsible for saving the files in the chosen directories, not the widget.

Comment: yeah, you are right - sfValidatorFile, i updated my question

Comment: Can you post the part of the `CouponActionForm` class where you define the validator?